# How to serve two laravel projects in nginx server with IP address?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-config

I setup a laravel project on Ubuntu server with nginx, now I need to deploy a second project in the same server, if I don't have a domain name but IP address, how must I define the server_name for my second project? I tried with **XX.XX.XX.XX/mysecondproject** but I had an error when I reload nginx. I really appreciate if you can help me with this question. Here is my nginx file.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/mysecondproject/public;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name XX.XX.XX.XX/mysecondproject;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Do you have different IP address for that second project?

Comment: If you are accessing the server using the IP address, then `server_name` should be the IP address, not the IP address concatenated with the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this approach worked for me. This way I have a first_project running at IP address (XX.XX.XX.XX) and a second application running at XX.XX.XX.XX/my_second_project. I used only the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file for setup my server. I hope it helps somebody in the future.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/my_first_project/public;

  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name XX.XX.XX.XX //my IP Address;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /my_second_project {
    alias /var/www/my_second_project/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @my_second_project;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

  location @my_second_project {
    rewrite /my_second_project/(.*)$ /my_second_project/index.php?/$1 last;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ferna Stereo,

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single ip addr for the instance like `10.0.1.20` and you want to serve both projects over the same ip address you can try the following configurations.

### Seperated by Port

Your instance is lisiting on IP `10.0.1.20`. Port `80` is the your App1 and Port `8080` is your App2.

```
#App1
server {
   server_name 10.0.1.20;
   listen 80;

   .....

}
#App2
server {
   server_name 10.0.1.20;
   listen 8080;

   .....

}
```

If you want to seperate your apps by location (/app1, /app2) and not by port.

### Seperate by Location

```
#AppServer 1
server {
   listen 8081;
   ......
}

#AppServer 2
server {
   listen 8080;
   ......
}


#ProxyServer
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 10.0.1.20;

   location /app1 {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       ......

   }
   location /app2 {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       ....
   }
}
```